# Data Grid View cursor

Tags: c#, winforms, bindingsource

My datagrid show a table from my sqlBd. I add a textBox for each column that for show each rows.

This is my code:

```
 private void CustomerViewToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingSource Clients_bs = new BindingSource();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dc.Con);
        con.Open();
        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Clients", con);

        da.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();

        dgCustomers.DataSource = dt;
        Clients_bs.DataSource = dt;

       txtBoxIdCustomers.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", Clients_bs,"id_Client"));                

        txtBoxFullName.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", Clients_bs, "prénom_Nom"));
        txtBoxAddress.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", Clients_bs, "adresse"));
        txtBoxCity.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", Clients_bs, "ville"));
        txtBoxProvince.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", Clients_bs, "province"));
        txtBoxPostal.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", Clients_bs, "code_Postal"));
        txtBoxPhone.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", Clients_bs, "numéro_Teléphone"));
    }
```

That fill my dataGrid like my table in sql, and my txtbox's shows the first row only whit the cursor pointing on the first row in my dataGrid.

I want to move the cursor of the data grid on the second row  and show txtbox's bind automatically on the second row ....

I can make whit a button previous and next, but not whit the cursor...

Thank's for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of this:

```
dgCustomers.DataSource = dt;
Clients_bs.DataSource = dt;
```

do this:

```
Clients_bs.DataSource = dt;
dgCustomers.DataSource = Clients_bs;
```

then it should work as the TextBoxes and the Grid have the same BindingSource ;-)

**Edit:**

and also, please, instead of this:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dc.Con);
con.Open();
da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Clients", con);

da.Fill(dt);
con.Close();
```

do this:

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection(dc.Con))
{
    con.Open();
    da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Clients", con);

    da.Fill(dt);
}
```